# NSSortDescriptor initWithKey:ascending:comparator: didn't work with localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare

Tags: cocoa, core-data

In a core data fetch request I want to sort the result case insensitive.
So I coded:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = 
     [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" 
                                 ascending:YES 
                                comparator:^(id s1, id s2) 
            {

                return [s1 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:s2];
            }];
```

but unfortunately the result is still:
 B U a c y z.

But the Block seems to be ok, because if I sort the result with that code:

```
NSMutableArray* names = ......
[names sortUsingComparator:^(id s1, id s2) 
     {

         return [s1 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:s2];
     }];
```

than the result is:
  a B c U y z.

Where is my fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution not with Block - but with selector:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
       [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"question" 
                                    ascending:YES 
                                    selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

if "name" is a string-attribute of a core data Entity it works well.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the NSFetchedRequest class. Did you report that to apple?

Comment: No I did not. I am not so familiar with the processes in the "apple world". @Lightforce: may be you an report the bug.

Answer (score 0):

If your result set is large and you're paging thru it (say using `NSFetchedResultsController` or `NSFetchRequest`'s `fetchLimit` and `fetchOffset`), you don't want to use `NSSortDescriptor`'s `initWithKey:ascending:selector:` because CoreData will fetch *all* the objects and sort them outside the database.

Instead, store a lowercased copy of the property you want to sort on, e.g., `lowercasedName`, and search on that using `NSSortDescriptor`'s `initWithKey:ascending:`.